# Passing timestamp variable from shell to gawk

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I want to take time difference of two time stamp but getting an error while passing timestamp variable from shell to`awk`.

Shell code:

```
FTIMESTAMP="2015-07-01 12:30:50"
gawk -v FTIMESTAMP=$FTIMESTAMP -v DSECONDS=$DSECONDS -f test.awk /home/abc/TShift.csv
```

Error is:

```
gawk: 12:30:50
gawk:   ^ syntax error
```

Escaping character is also not working `FTIMESTAMP="2015-07-01 12\:30\:50"`.

I have another timestamp in `awk` and want to take time difference between them.

Comment: See how that's one of the examples at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote variables to prevent shell from performing [split+glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906):

```
gawk -v FTIMESTAMP="$FTIMESTAMP" -v DSECONDS="$DSECONDS" ...
```

A note that `-v var="$shell_var"` will expand escape sequences in `$shell_var`. You need to use `ENVIRON` or `ARGV` variables to pass `$shell_var` as-is from shell to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

try either

```
gawk -v FTIMESTAMP="$FTIMESTAMP" -v DSECONDS=$DSECONDS -f test.awk /home/abc/TShift.csv
```

there is a white in `$FTIMESTAMP`

or in calling shell

```
FTIMESTAMP="2015-07-01 12:30:50"
export FTIMESTAMP
```

and in awk's script (in `BEGIN  { .. }` section)

```
FTIMESTAMP=ENVIRON["FTIMESTAMP"] ;
```